# Is there a way to search other table for word which has a past due date but works in conditional format

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

I've looked till I am blue in the face. In Sheet/Cell (Customer) I want to have a conditional format to put in the **Past Due** column to show. I need it to search the **Customer** Column for something like **Bob** in **Payments** sheet for the name of customer but the last time they paid to reflect if its past due.

I started using =TODAY()-Payments!H9>30 and tried other variants but didn't come up with something I want.

**Customer** database sheet

| Customer | Services | Phone | Email | Address | Cost | Past Due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Install | 123456789 | something@gmail | Something street | $15 | Conditional Formatting |
| Fred | Install | 123456789 | something@gmail | Something street | $15 | Conditional Formatting |
| Ted | Install | 123456789 | something@gmail | Something street | $15 | Conditional Formatting |

**Payments** sheet

| Customer | Services | Phone | Cost | Paid Next | Due Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Install | 123456789 | $15 | March 29, 2021 | April 28, 2021 |
| Fred | Install | 123456789 | $15 | March 29, 2021 | April 28, 2021 |
| Ted | Install | 123456789 | $15 | March 29, 2021 | April 28, 2021 |
| Bob | Install | 123456789 | $15 | May 28, 2021 | June 28, 2021 |
| Fred | Install | 123456789 | $15 | May 28, 2021 | June 28, 2021 |
| Ted | Install | 123456789 | $15 | May 28, 2021 | June 28, 2021 |

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific about what makes a customer 'past due'.  However, I think you'll be on the right track if your formatting condition uses a VLookup on what's in column A to find the payments detail in the payments table to calculate whatever you need for a past due condition.

Comment: 30 days from the last time they made a payment which would go off of the Next Due Date. I guess being past due on the Next Due Date

Comment: From your sample data no due date is greater than 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

After clarifying your question I see that there is a whole history of payments for each customer that you need to summarize in some way to see if they are past due.  You are really getting beyond Excel's capability and need the power of a relational database.

You could investigate using PowerQuery to summarize the Payments table, selecting the record with the most recent payment, but these queries do not automatically refresh - you would need to manually  refresh each time.

Comment: Lol...Yeah after all the searching I done there wasn't nothing coming close to what I want it to do. I usually find a formula and play around with it until I figure it out myself on other things.....Can excel copy rows to another spreadsheet of previous dates when a new one (payment) is made? Keep a running log for a month then erases old data with month old dates.

Comment: Yes, but it's all VBA code to manage the automation.  ...and another question.